# Choosing a rotation method for ESEM

Tags: rotation

I am trying to decide on which oblique rotation method to use for my ESEM analysis (with MLR estimator). MPLUS provides a number of options (GEOMIN, QUARTIMIN, OBLIMIN, CRAWFER, etc.). I was wondering if someone knows of any applied guides that would describe when one should use these rotation methods? I have been trying to find such sources but they typically go into the math behind the methods rather than practical recommendations about when one should choose one method over another.

Thank you very much in advance.